# Jquery PopUp in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Please provide me code to how to open jquery popup by clicking on asp.net gridview row to show each row's data in the popup

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you try yourself first? Google is my friend, Try to  find on it, you will find tons of results and ways to do so.

Comment: In asp.net You can use Ajax ModalPopup Control refer : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34996/ASP-NET-AJAX-Control-Toolkit-ModalPopupExtender-Co  http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://www.encodedna.com/2013/03/gridview-row-mouseover.htm

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202824/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070407-1.aspx

and some technical details on

[Display details on moving mouse over a row in gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895072/display-details-on-moving-mouse-over-a-row-in-gridview)